# Can't check website's status if it's using HTTPS protocol

Tags: python, file, python-requests

I am trying to check if a website from text document returns Status 200(working) or Status 400(not working). When I add website to the array of urls that I need to check manually, the script works perfectly and checks everything. But when I add url from text document into array, it only works with websites that start with http protocol but not https protocol. What could be causing this issue ?
`code`

```
import requests

def get_url_status(urls):  # checks status for each url in list urls

  for url in urls:
      try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        print(url + "\tStatus: " + str(r.status_code))
      except Exception as e:
        print(url + "\tNA FAILED TO CONNECT\t" + str(e))
  return None

def main():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        urls = ["https://www.youtube.com"]
        for line in f:
           urls.append(line)

    get_url_status(urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`code`
Youtube link from urls array returns Status 200, but if I put exactly same link inside of the text document, it will return NA FAILED TO CONNECT Caused by NewConnectionError. Meanwhile, if you put http link inside of the text document, it will work fine and will return either Status 200 or 404. What is this caused by ? Does it have something to do with HTTPS protocol?

Comment: The lines you read from the file will end with newline characters.  You need to strip that off before it's a valid URL - apparently, `requests` is doing this for you only in the case of HTTP.

Comment: How can I strip off that \n character ?

Comment: `"text\n".strip('\n')`. So may be replace `for line in f:` with `for line in (line.strip('\n') for line in f):`

Comment: Yep that works perfectly, thank you so so much